# Select records without a relationship

Tags: mysql

I have three table

- tbl_part - Contains an indexed list of parts
- tbl_product - Contains an indexed list of products
- tbl_part_product - Contains the relationships between parts and products.

I'd like to select all the parts that AREN'T related to a product but having some 20k+ parts my query is just too slow. Does anyone know a better way of how I can accomplish this?

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_part AS p
LEFT JOIN tbl_part_product AS pp ON pp.ref_part_id = p.part_id
WHERE pp.ref_part_id IS NULL
```

Comment: It will generate spurious tuples.

Comment: Are you using foreign keys in your `tbl_part_product` table?

Comment: Btw, do you have *any* keys or indices on your tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like an INDEX issue, your query won't get quicker than it already is by modifying it.

If you don't already have an index on `ref_part_id`, Try this, it should speed up your query quite a bit:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_part_product  ADD INDEX (ref_part_id);
```

Comment: Yep, that speed my query up. What exactly is that doing though?

Comment: It's telling the DB to "index" the ref_part_id column, i.e. to add a quick look-up on the column.  It's similar to an index at the back of a book... makes the DB faster at finding things. :)  More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: That makes sense. It seems to have solved my problem taking my query from a horrible 60 seconds to a tinny 0.09 seconds. I'll accept as soon as I'm allowed.

Comment: Awesome.  Glad it worked.  While you're at it, you should look through your database and add indexes to any (non primary key) columns that are used in joins or where clauses.  It'll improve your overall performance considerably.